# Import data from multiple csv files to one Excel worksheet and calculate averages

Tags: excel, csv, macros, excel-2010, vba

I’m trying to create a Macro in Excel 2010 which imports a single column of numerical data from an unknown number of semicolon delimited csv files, which are stored in a sub folder, to sequential columns in a master workbook. The macro should run from the open master workbook.

The starting cell is known, but the size of the column range can vary.

Every single file name is different.

If the file name is “File name – 60.00mm.csv”,

I wish to use “60.00” as the column  header and for it to be formatted as a number. This needs to be taken from the name of the csv workbook as it’s not part of the sheet name. I’ve managed to do this.

Column A of the master workbook has the title “Scan number” and the rows are populated with the numbers 1, 2, 3 etc to however many rows are required for the largest data range. I’ve yet to work out how to do this.

At a row below the last filled row of the largest data range, I want the average of all of the data above to be computed, excluding the header row. The title of this row in column A should be “Average”. I’ve workout out how to compute the average but don’t know how to output it to a row below the last filled row of the largest data range. It's currently in a cell directly below the data set.

I’ve managed to create a macro which will find and loop through all csv files, and select and copy the relevant data range, but  I’m having trouble pasting it in the master workbook without using “Activate” and “Select”. It also skips column A and pastes to column B.

Also, I have not gotten it to work without opening and closing each csv file sequentially.

Can anyone please assist with improving this code and the most efficient way to provide the missing parts?

Current Code:
    Option Explicit
    Sub Import()

```
Dim New_Path As String 
Dim CSV_WB As Workbook
Dim Data As Variant 
Dim CSV_files As String 
Dim lastrow_CSV As Long 
Dim lastrow As Long 
Dim lastcol As Long 
Dim CSV_Sht_Name As String 
Dim CSV_Wbk_Title As String 
Dim averageRange As Variant 

New_Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "Sub folder"
CSV_files = Dir(New_Path & "*.csv")

Do While Len(CSV_files) > 0

    Workbooks.OpenText _
    Filename:=New_Path & CSV_files, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Semicolon:=True, _
    Local:=True

'Copy data.
    Set CSV_WB = Workbooks(CSV_files)
    CSV_Sht_Name = ActiveSheet.Name
    CSV_Wbk_Title = Val(Left(Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11), 5))
    lastrow_CSV = CSV_WB.Worksheets(CSV_Sht_Name).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Data = CSV_WB.Worksheets(CSV_Sht_Name).Range("C14:C" & lastrow_CSV).Copy

'Paste Data
    Windows("Master Workbook").Activate

    lastcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Cells(1, lastcol).Offset(, 1).Value = CSV_Wbk_Title

    Cells(1, lastcol).Offset(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

'Add average.
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, lastcol + 1).End(xlUp).Row

    averageRange = Range(Cells(2, lastcol + 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol + 1))

    With Cells(lastrow + 1, lastcol + 1)
        .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(averageRange)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    CSV_WB.Close

    CSV_files = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you can modify to read the data directly into the master without opening each file.

```
'Created by Fredrik Östman www.scoc.se
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim file_text_tmp As String
Dim i As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("E:\")

field_num = 3
delimiter = ";"

col = 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    Cells(1, col) = Val(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 11), 5))
    Open objFile.Path For Input As #1
        Row = 2
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, file_text_tmp
            If field_num > 1 Then
                For k = 1 To field_num - 1
                    file_text_tmp = Right(file_text_tmp, Len(file_text_tmp) - InStr(1, file_text_tmp, delimiter))
                Next k
            End If
            if InStr(1, file_text_tmp, delimiter) = 0 then
                Cells(Row, col)=file_text_tmp
            else
                Cells(Row, col) = Left(file_text_tmp, InStr(1, file_text_tmp, delimiter) - 1)
            end if
            Row = Row + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
    col = col + 1
Next objFile

Rows("2:14").Delete ' looks like you are only copying from row 14, which is row 15 in my code

'Add average.
Row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
For i = 1 To Col - 1
    With Cells(Row, i)
    .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(Row - 1, i)))
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

Comment: The add average part worked brilliantly, so thank you.

But the import code gives me an error of "Invalid Procedure call or argument.' at the line after the End If statement:

Cells(Row, col) = Left(file_text_tmp, InStr(1, file_text_tmp, ",") - 1)

Comment: Had the incorrect delimiter "," instead of ";". Also if the third field is the last one it would fail. I have edited the code above.